# Who decides if file format is popular enough to have its own MIME type?

Tags: file-format, mime-types

Who decides, if a program is popular enough to have its own MIME type?

Right now, I program something for dealing with .srt subtitles - and while on wikipedia, it has `application/x-subrip` MIME type, nothing like that is seen in the official IANA MIME list.

How is that determined? Who decides, if `srt` is popular enough to have its own listing in IANA MIME list?

Comment: Also, I *think* that the question is constructive, since it's a straightforward question that is 100% answerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow a few links from that IANA (MIME) Media Types page, you'll find [RFC 4288](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4288), which describes the process. There are at least four "trees":

- Standards
- Vendor
- Personal/Vanity
- Experimental

Your question is about the standards tree:

> Registrations in the standards tree MUST be approved by the IESG and MUST correspond to a formal publication by a recognized standards body.

- A "recognized standards body" drafts a proposal
- It is also announced on an official mailing list
- Interested parties discuss it
- The IESG approves it (or not)
- An appointed "media types reviewer" makes sure the proposal meets all detail requirements
- It is published by IANA

So to answer your question, a standards body must first decide it is "popular enough" to pursue, and then the Internet Engineering Steering Group (a part of the IETF, Internet Engineering Task Force) must agree.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted, thanks. Also thanks for the RPC link.